# tinymce column width resizeable table

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I am using tinymce & it provides the table plugin by which table is created. Table is plotted in textarea & due to contenteditable property the table can be resize using handle It is when I resize the table or merge the two cells the width of the cells is lost.

Even of the merge cells or normal cells the width is never calculated correct. On firebug i used various jquery stmt such as

$(td).width() - gives 0px
$(td).attr("style") - style has the same width that is set during insertion so there is no change
$(td).css("width") - give 0px or sometime very less values.
$(td)[0].offsetWidth - gives 0px

I do see the tbl width & height has correct value in style attribute & is set automatically depending of the how handle is dragged but column width height is never set though i see they are correctly resized.